# How to get reference from low level class attribute to some top level attributes within the same class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, class

How to get a reference from low level class attribute to some top level attributes within the same class in C#?

Yeah.. Let's imagine there is some class with 10 levels of its hierarchy. And I need in some moment get a reference from the 10th level to some attribute at the 3th level. And change it. Let's imagine that some of the down-level attribute is a Timer which does something itself and needs this access.

Is it possible to do?

Thanks for any clue!

UPDATES:
*Indeed  we can do some external object which will do this job... But the idea is to keep inside of the class all logic...*

Comment: 10 levels of inheritance? Yikes! How about preferring composition over inheritance?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input... Yup... I have a really complex class. I don't want to create any external Managers to change some class attributes. Instead of it I want to implement this Manager(read Timer) within some level of the class. That's why I need to access from the Timer event to some top level attributes of the class.

Comment: You cannot change attributes, they are baked into the assembly metadata at compile time.  Avoid addressing complexity by adding more layers.

Comment: So there is only 1 solution which is to create some external mechanism to process class? I mean the idea that class changes itself like a black box.

Comment: Is it possible to provide  some kind of SELF reference to down levels of the class? It's like to get the  owner of the property? I mean is there any cross references system within a class?

Comment: Indeed we can iterate from top level to downstairs within some top level class method. Can we do it to get upstairs levels from the bottom of the hierarchy?

Comment: Dmitry, you used the word property in one of your previous statements. Are you talking about attributes, or properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I am not sure what class hierarchy requires 10 levels (this seems overly complex and should be re-evaluated see Structural Patterns from Gang of Four like Composite or Decorator so that you can reduce the very large inheritance structure).

I think understanding the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) would be beneficial as well.  Essentially you should not search for the property or attribute you want to change, you should just ask for it.

Simply create an interface like ISpecificAttributeProvider that the 3rd level implements and then in your 10th level check if your current object implements that interface.

```
public interface ISpecificAttributeProvider
{
   object GetSpecificAttribute();
}

public class ThirdLevel : SecondLevel, ISpecificAttributeProvider
{
   private object _attributeInQuestion;

   public object GetSpecificAttribute()
   {
      return _attributeInQuestion;
   }
}

public class TenthLevel: NinthLevel
{      
   public void Method()
   {
      if (this is ISpecificAttributeProvider)
         object attribute = GetSpecificAttribute();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi! It seems this is what I asked for! Thank you!